# HTML, CSS, inline-block Safari browser

Tags: css, windows, for-loop, safari

the next positions of elements

```css
 
           * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
    }

 .container {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
    }
    
.container>div {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 50%;
     height: 100px;
     font-size: 1rem;
     bacground-color: #654fca;
     }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
      <div class='item-left'>
      <div class='item-right'>
    </div>
```

all browsers position the element-left and the element-right horizontally, one after another. Only a nice browser Safari for Windows puts upright, pressing them to the left. Who can explain, or tell where to read about calculating the widths in the Safari browser, because if you reduce the width of the elements as 49%, the elements become horizontal, but with the edge remaining space.

Comment: What if you use `box-sizing: border-box` with 50% ?

Comment: why are you debuging on windows safari? Windows safari is outdated and does not represent the current version of Safari browsers. Besides none usees safari on windows anymore. Why don't you debug on a real safari device?

Comment: и да, я забыл добавить box-sizing: border-box into this code

Comment: i have not devices with MacOS or IOs

Answer (score 0):

Update your css this way and you won't need to worry about  browser compatibility:

Add to your css: ( keep your original styles)

```
 .container>div.item-left {
    float:left;
  } 

 .container>div.item-right {
     float:right;
   }
```

Comment: )))) floats use only for float text by image

Comment: What? No buddy, you  can use it to align any element not only text or image.  If you are trying to solve your issue then that is your answer but you if you want to know why safari does it this way, then keep digging for another 5 years

Comment: ***then keep digging for another 5 years –**** )))) yes, i`m try to know

Answer (score 0):

If you work with safari and want to find out the width, you first have to enable the developer toolbar in the browser.
You have to open the safari preferences and click on the advanced tab. Then select "Show Develop menu" in the menu bar box at the bottom of the pane. Now you can close this bar. Now right click anywhere inside of the content area and select "Inspect Element".
Now a new window should appear in the bottom of the browser. When you hover a part of the window, the code will appear. The first number is the width. Hope i could help you.

Comment: width of elements less than container 1px